# Python typing - is there a way to avoid importing of optional type if it's None?

Tags: python, pypi, typing, mypy

Let's say we have a function definition like this:

```py
def f(*, model: Optional[Type[pydantic.BaseModel]] = None)
```

So the function doesn't require `pydantic` to be installed until you pass something as a `model`. Now let's say we want to pack the function into pypi package. And my question is if there's a way to avoid bringing `pydantic` into the package dependencies only the sake of type checking?

Comment: you don't have to import the complete module. you can import the specific model `from pydantic import BaseModel`

Comment: An option to consider is using a string type name, e.g. `Optional[Type["pydantic.BaseModel"]]`. Your code will then run fine without the `pydantic` module being installed. It can still be used for static type checking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried to follow [dspenser's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632600/3694363), but I found mypy still giving me `Name 'pydantic' is not defined` error. Then I found this [chapter in the docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#import-cycles) and it seems to be working in my case too:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import pydantic
```

You can use normal clases (instead of string literals) with `__future__.annotations` (python 3.8.1):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional, Type

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import pydantic


def f(*, model: Optional[Type[pydantic.BaseModel]] = None):
    pass
```

If for some reason you can't use `__future__.annotations`, e.g. you're on python < 3.7, use typing with string literals from [dspenser's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632600/3694363).

Comment: Yes, under my approach, mypy would complain about the missing import, but your code would execute successfully.

Comment: @dspencer  I upvoted you, but that really ought to be merged into your answer.

Comment: @JLPeyret Thanks for the advice - I have merged this into my answer as you recommend.

Comment: That chapter is missing from the 'latest' build of the docs. See the 'stable' build instead: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#import-cycles

Answer (score 6):

Python's `typing` module can use string type names, as well as the type itself, as you have in your example.

If you don't want the type to be evaluated when the code is run, and an exception thrown if the module has not been imported, then you may prefer to use the string name. Your code snippet would then be:

```py
def f(*, model: Optional[Type["pydantic.BaseModel"]] = None)
```

Your static type checking using `mypy` should continue to work, but your package will no longer always require the dependency on `pydantic`.

As you discovered in the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#import-cycles), python's `typing` module includes a way to specify that some imports are only required for (string literal) type annotations:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import pydantic
```

This will execute the `import pydantic` statement only when `TYPE_CHECKING` is `True`, primarily when using `mypy` to analyze the types in the code. When running the program normally, the import statement is not executed. For this reason, the option is only to be used with string literal type hints; otherwise, the missing import will cause the program's normal execution to fail.

As **lazy evaluation** of type hints is to be implemented in Python 4.0,

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

can be used to enable this behaviour in Python 3. With this import statement, string literal types are not required.

Comment: > are only required for (string literal) type annotations

You're not actually restricted to string literals this way

Comment: Of course not, but the docs say: "if the import is only needed for type annotations in forward references (string literals) or comments)". There is no use for `TYPE_CHECKING` if you are using your types in their raw forms, e.g. `pydantic.BaseModel` as the import will then always be required to execute your code.

Comment: I also found a strange flake8 reaction on passing only `"pydantic.BaseModel"` as a string. In case you'd like to change or include it: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/issues/621

Comment: @imbolc Your link seems to not work, can you check?

Comment: I see, they probably have to approve my issue or something, copied it into a gist: https://gist.github.com/imbolc/e47632323cd53f4c26514864ecc38460

Comment: Also I found you can avoid using string literals with `__future__.annotations`, an example is in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634118/795856

Comment: @imbolc Your original question is unrelated to `flake8` - I would consider that a separate issue.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like

```py
try:
    from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel
except ImportError:
    PydanticBaseModel = None
```

I don't think it's better than what [dspencer proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632600/3694363), but sometimes some weird styleguide may forbid you from using string type names, so I just wanted to point another solution out.